# What does AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled mean and how to get rid of it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I recently try to learn how to use Amazon AWS iOS SDK since I would like to put some files on server allowed to be downloaded by app users.

I have download the [samples](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3TransferManager-Sample/Objective-C) provided by Amazon and studied them:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3TransferManager-Sample/Objective-C

Thing went pretty well with uploading files to my S3 bucket until I tried to download the images from the bucket.

I traced the codes and found where the problem happened.

```
[[transferManager download:self.downloadRequest1] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    if (task.error != nil){
        if(task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled && task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused){
            NSLog(@"%s Error: [%@]",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, task.error);
            self.downloadStatusLabel.text = StatusLabelFailed;
        }
    } else {
        self.downloadRequest1 = nil;
        downloadCount++;
        if(3 == downloadCount){
            self.downloadStatusLabel.text = StatusLabelCompleted;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

I printed the value of task.error.code and found it is `1` (`AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled`).
Since there is no exception handling of `AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled`, the program does not show error message and failed to download files.

I tried to find what `AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled` means but no luck.

Does anyone know why the error code = `1` (`AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled`) and how to solve it? I believe I must miss something very simple considering this is an tutorial provided by Amazon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some studies, finally I figured out it is Permissions issue.

So when I was creating a Identity Pool, the system asked you if you want to enable access to Unauthenticated Identities.
And if you enable this option, AWS would give you a default unauthenticated Identities postfixed by Unauth_DefaultRole.
The thing is AWS does not automatically give the permission of  "Get" to this identity.
You still need to add this Action into the policy of  xxxUnauth_DefaultRole.

So, here is my modified policy to allow to unauthenticated users to download files from my bucket.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [{
    "Action": [
        "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
        "cognito-sync:*",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:Get*"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": [
        "*"
    ]
}]
}
```

Hope this can help someone who is also new for AWS.